# React prime calendar component shows when I click on input div but suddenly gets removed or disappears and when i change tab it comes back again

Tags: reactjs, user-interface

The issue is that the Calendar component is rendered in the DOM but suddenly gets removed or disappears. The cause of this issue needs to be identified and resolved, possibly by examining the code for any conflicting or erroneous logic related to rendering or visibility of the Calendar component.

````
 <Calendar
                    id="range"
                    className="mr-4 mb-2 w-100"
                    placeholder="Select date range"
                    dateFormat="dd/mm/yy"
                    value={createdAt}
                    hideOnDateTimeSelect={true}
                    onChange={(e) => {
                      if (e.value) {
                        setCreatedAt(e.value);
                        if (e.value[0] && e.value[1]) {
                          lazyParams.filters["createdAt"] = [
                            moment(e.value[0]).format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
                            moment(e.value[1]).format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
                          ];

                          setLazyParams(lazyParams);
                          setTimeout(() => {
                            getEarnings();
                          }, 500);
                        }
                      } else {
                        setCreatedAt([]);
                        delete lazyParams.filters["createdAt"];
                        setLazyParams(lazyParams);
                        setTimeout(() => {
                          getEarnings();
                        }, 500);
                      }
                    }}
                    selectionMode="range"
                    showButtonBar
                    readOnlyInput
                  />
              ```
````